# Disable USB support for mega32u4

Tags: usb, arduino-leonardo, compile, atmega32u4

I have a custom Leonardo board (mega32u4-based) that does not use at all the USB features.
When I build my sketch (vscode and platformio) I read:

```
Compiling .pio/build/leonardo/FrameworkArduino/CDC.cpp.o
Indexing .pio/build/leonardo/libFrameworkArduinoVariant.a
Compiling .pio/build/leonardo/FrameworkArduino/HardwareSerial.cpp.o
Archiving .pio/build/leonardo/lib02e/libFadeLed.a
Compiling .pio/build/leonardo/FrameworkArduino/HardwareSerial0.cpp.o
Indexing .pio/build/leonardo/lib02e/libFadeLed.a
Compiling .pio/build/leonardo/FrameworkArduino/HardwareSerial1.cpp.o
Compiling .pio/build/leonardo/FrameworkArduino/HardwareSerial2.cpp.o
Compiling .pio/build/leonardo/FrameworkArduino/HardwareSerial3.cpp.o
Archiving .pio/build/leonardo/libfa3/libWire.a
Indexing .pio/build/leonardo/libfa3/libWire.a
Compiling .pio/build/leonardo/FrameworkArduino/IPAddress.cpp.o
Compiling .pio/build/leonardo/FrameworkArduino/PluggableUSB.cpp.o
Compiling .pio/build/leonardo/FrameworkArduino/Print.cpp.o
Compiling .pio/build/leonardo/FrameworkArduino/Stream.cpp.o
Compiling .pio/build/leonardo/FrameworkArduino/Tone.cpp.o
Compiling .pio/build/leonardo/FrameworkArduino/USBCore.cpp.o
Compiling .pio/build/leonardo/FrameworkArduino/WInterrupts.c.o
Compiling .pio/build/leonardo/FrameworkArduino/WMath.cpp.o
Compiling .pio/build/leonardo/FrameworkArduino/WString.cpp.o
Compiling .pio/build/leonardo/FrameworkArduino/abi.cpp.o
Compiling .pio/build/leonardo/FrameworkArduino/hooks.c.o
Compiling .pio/build/leonardo/FrameworkArduino/main.cpp.o
Compiling .pio/build/leonardo/FrameworkArduino/new.cpp.o
Compiling .pio/build/leonardo/FrameworkArduino/wiring.c.o
Compiling .pio/build/leonardo/FrameworkArduino/wiring_analog.c.o
Compiling .pio/build/leonardo/FrameworkArduino/wiring_digital.c.o
Compiling .pio/build/leonardo/FrameworkArduino/wiring_pulse.S.o
Compiling .pio/build/leonardo/FrameworkArduino/wiring_pulse.c.o
Compiling .pio/build/leonardo/FrameworkArduino/wiring_shift.c.o
```

I wonder if I can disable the USB support (CDC, PluggableUSB, USBCore) and also network stuff (IPAddress) in order to save flash space.

Comment: I think the optimizer will kick that stuff out when you don't use it. So that should already happen.

Comment: USBCore creates the com port for upload and handles the 1200 baud 'touch' for reset to bootloader before upload

Comment: @Juraj, yes but as I said I have no bootloader neither any USB com port

Comment: @Juraj done. I can't find any entry about `IPAddress` but all the USB stuff is there

Comment: main.cpp has `USBDevice.attach();`

Comment: @Juraj sorry I don't understand you. Which `main.cpp`? Anyway, is it possible to save flash space disabling the USB stuff?

Comment: https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/main.cpp

Comment: I doubt the optimizer will determine that it can eliminate the USB ISRs and their dependencies. Where the core conditionally compiles the USB parts based on the presence of USB peripheral register definitions, you're left with a bunch of options that aren't great. E.g. modifying the core to not include these features all or to extend the expression with something like `&& !defined(NO_ARDUINO_USB_STACK)`. Or to fake out the core by (not/un)defining the USB peripheral with a modified avrlibc, again perhaps conditionally. And maybe modifying board.txt to pass feature flags for that purpose.